# How does xDB track individual visits?

Tags: xdb, cookies

With Sitecore 8.x, there is no longer a cookie associated with the individual visit (though of course the visitor cookie, `SC_GLOBAL_ANALYTICS_COOKIE` is still there). How does xDB track individual visits? Is there a browser-stored entity that corresponds to the Interaction ID, or is this purely managed on the server side, i.e. requests coming from a specific visitor cookie are considered to be one interaction while the server session lasts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xDB online visits, in most cases, map one-to-one to ASP.NET sessions. Generally, ASP.NET sessions are tracked in the browser using the cookie `ASP.NET_SessionId`, and the actual visit state (including the `InteractionId`) is kept in the session store you've [**configured**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state_configuration_scenarios) in Sitecore.

The reason I said "in most cases" in the sentence above is because there are cases when xDB contacts and live sessions are merged. For example, if a person opens a Sitecore website on two devices at the same time and then authenticates on both (resulting in a call to [**`Session.Identify()`**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/identifying_contacts)), the two previously anonymous contacts, along with their currently running visits, will be [**merged together**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/merge_contacts). Hence, multiple ASP.NET sessions may sometimes end up as a single interaction in xDB.

Answer (score 5):

As you suspect; this is now session based. The principle works like this.

Every time a new session starts; 2 sessions are actually kicked off on the server.

- A Device Session

> correspond to a contact making an interaction using a device. A device
>   session begins with the first page request but also captures other
>   requests made during the same time period

- A Contact Session

> begins together with the device session. When a contact uses multiple
>   devices at the same time the contact session will continue as a series
>   of overlapping device sessions. Contact information collected in one
>   device session is immediately made available in all other device
>   sessions. The contact session ends when the last of the connected
>   device sessions has ended and all the data associated with the contact
>   is saved to the xDB.

Then it becomes a matter of identifying the user in a *device session* and mapping to a *contact session*. To do that, xDB relies on the user doing something to identify themselves. Usually this would be logging in, but could also be something like clicking an Email Campaign link. If a user does nothing to identify himself, the Device/Contact session linking is never done.

If the user is identified, xDB does a merge of the primary contact record for the user, and the corresponding contact session(s).

Source: [Contact Tracking](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/contact_tracking)
Source: [Merging Contacts](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/merge_contacts)

Comment: How does this translate in terms of Page views(PV). If a session is merged , does it mean that PV is 1 for that visitor